# Using class object as generic type

Tags: java, generics, exception

I'm not entirely sure of how to ask this question, which is also why I'm not sure about the title and so on. Here goes.

Say you have a object `Foo foo = new Foo()`. Is it possible to write code like `new ArrayList<foo.getClass()>()`, which would on runtime be equivalent to `new ArrayList<Foo>()`?

Another, but related question is: Suppose that the class `Foo` extends `Exception`. Is it then possible to write something like

```
try{
    // ...
} catch(foo.getClass() e) {
    //
}
```

which would translate into

```
try{
    // ...
} catch(Foo e) {
    //
}
```

?

Whether this would be horrible to do, is not the important part. However, I would like to hear qualified opinions anyway.

Comment: Runtime generics, we get these pretty often here :) In run time `ArrayList<T>` just becomes `ArrayList`. Erasure occurs. Just to be annoying - it's possible in C#.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No it's not. C#'s generics are still *mainly* a compile-time type-safety feature (except for the ability to do `typeof(T)` meaningfully, i.e. you get a type token passed around for free), and thus don't make sense with a type you get using reflection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible in the Java language specification.  Generic parameters are purely a compile-time type-safety mechanism, so defining them at runtime is non-sensical.

Class literals in the code are not interchangeable with `Class<T>` objects, due to their inherently different roles.  The latter only has meaning at runtime, and can vary dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle, but existent difference between a type and its Class literal.

The class literal is an object that models a type. Among other things, it provides details about the type's implementation.

When you reference an object you use a type. The same holds for generic parameters. They are represented, on the source code, with a type.

For example, while writing

```
String foo = "foo";
```

is legal

```
"".getClass() foo = "foo"
```

is not.

I hope this makes sense.

Edit: A usual pattern, when working with Generics, is to pass the Class as an argument.

```
<T> doSomething(Class<T> clazz);
```

Edit2: edited according to @millimoose comments

Comment: This is a confusing answer, since `Type` is a JDK class that actually means something else than what you describe. Also, the pattern you mention is useful but it's of no use to the OP.

Comment: @millimoose You are correct, I should have not used a capital T for type. I made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support that syntax, but if your goal is to create a Collection whose type is determined by the type of an instance, create a *typed method*, eg:

```
public static <T> List<T> createList(T object) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(object);
    return list;
}
```

Whatever type you pass in will determine the type of the List returned. It's not a runtime determination - it's a compile time check, but it's the closest thing to how I interpret your intention.